# How to edit build properties of a Java Library

Tags: modbus

There seem to be some similar questions, but nothing quite specific enough, I hope this is OK.

I am wondering how to edit the build properties of the Jamod MODBUS library so as to use the RxTx API instead of the deprecated javax.comm. The Library page says this is supported:

> You will need an implementation of the Java Communications API extension (javax.comm) installed to be able to run serial modbus applications.
>   Note that there is also support for building with the gnu.io prefix (RXTX), via the boolean build property build.serial.gnu (true will cause the build process to replace the javax.comm prefix with gnu.io in the sources used for builds).

More info here: http://jamod.sourceforge.net/development/project_build.html

I am unsure how to access this file, or the technique for doing so. Do I need to create it or edit and existing one? I have look for build.xml in the project, but no luck, and have googled many times. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the proyect source (you can download it from [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download)) with an IDE (for example Netbeans) then replace every appearance of javax.comm by gnu.io, from [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download), add RXTXcomm.jar library to project, and if you are using windows  then copy  and rxtxSerial.dll for example to C:\windows\system32.

It will work. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
The " Modbus Jamod Project - Original " folder contains the original project is available at
Web http://jamod.sourceforge.net/ . This project has a significant dependence :

[1 ] javax.comm : comm : jar :3.0 -u1
Description : The Java Communications 3.0 API is a Java extension That Facilitates develop developing platform -independent communications applications for technologies : such as Smart Cards , embedded systems, and point -of -sale devices , financial services devices , fax , modems, display terminals , and robotic equipment .

This API is not available from Oracle repositories .

That's why you have to open the " Jamod -1.2 -SNAPSHOT - sources.jar " project and recompile using other libraries for serial communication. This project is now ready to " Modbus Jamod Project with CXR " to 64 Bits.




METHOD OF SOLUTION OF DEPENDENCE
-------------------------------------------

To recompile the Jamod (Modbus Jamod Project - Original) project, you must open the project with Netbeans clear the javax.comm library , and replaced with the rxtx library. CXR This library can be selected which are in the " CXR - Serial comms Java " folder , ie :
[1 ] MFZ - rxtx -2.2- 20081207 -linux- i386
[2 ] MFZ - rxtx -2.2- 20081207 -x86_64 -linux
[3 ] MFZ - rxtx -2.2- 20081207 -win- ia64
[4 ] MFZ - rxtx -2.2- x64 -win- 20081207
[5 ] MFZ - rxtx -2.2- x86 -win- 20081207

We must take into account the following when choosing :

Windows
-------

Select a binary build - x64 or x86 (based on Which version of
the JVM you are installing to)

NOTE : You MUST match your architecture . You can not install the i386
version on a 64 - bit version of the JDK and vice - versa.

For a JDK installation:

Copy RXTXcomm.jar ---> <JAVA_HOME> \ jre \ lib \ ext
Copy rxtxSerial.dll ---> <JAVA_HOME> \ jre \ bin
Copy rxtxParallel.dll ---> <JAVA_HOME> \ jre \ bin

Linux
-----

Select a binary build - x86_64 or i386 (based on Which version of
the JVM you are installing to)

NOTE : You MUST match your architecture . You can not install the i386
version on a 64 - bit version of the JDK and vice - versa.

For a JDK installation on i386 architecture =

Copy RXTXcomm.jar ---> <JAVA_HOME> / jre / lib / ext
Copy librxtxSerial.so ---> <JAVA_HOME> / jre/lib/i386 /
Copy librxtxParallel.so ---> <JAVA_HOME> / jre/lib/i386 /

NOTE : For a JDK installation on architecture = x86_64 , just change the
i386 to x86_64 above.

-------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------

After this replace the javax.comm library , the Jamod (Modbus Jamod Project - Original) project is recompiled , and the generated Jar Crossover is added.

When the Crossover project contains the library Jamod repaired , it will have to also add the RXTX library to Crossover.

Done.

-------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a copy of a build.xml file if you download the source ZIP of version 1.2rc1 at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamod/files/jamod/1.2/jamod-1.2rc1-src.zip/download

If you unzip, you will find build.xml and build-snap.xml, as well as the build.properties file, which lets you specify the build.serial.gnu.

You then just need to install ant and run it in the directory to initiate the build.

Edit: I also didn't have Apache Forrest installed, which appears to be using for generating the docs, so I needed to comment out all references to Forrest in the build.xml as well.